# Does Franz (multi messenger) work on elementary freya?

Tags: release-freya, applications

As the title says, does [Franz](http://meetfranz.com) work on elementary os freya?

If so, how to install it?

Comment: Never used myself. It can be useful reading this link to install it.  http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/whatsapp-skype-hangouts-e-outros-mensageiros-no-mesmo-lugar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Franz works perfect in Loki, should't be a Problem in Freya. Do the following in terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/franz

wget -qO- https://github.com/meetfranz/franz-app/releases/download/4.0.4/Franz-linux-x64-4.0.4.tgz | sudo tar xvz -C /opt/franz/

sudo wget "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/360/1*v86tTomtFZIdqzMNpvwIZw.png" -O /opt/franz/franz-icon.png

sudo bash -c "cat <<EOF > /usr/share/applications/franz.desktop                                                                 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Franz
Comment=
Exec=/opt/franz/Franz
Icon=/opt/franz/franz-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Messaging,Internet
EOF"
```

Everything should work fine now.

Comment: As some background, Franz is distributed as standalone files, rather than a .deb package. This block of commands downloads Franz to /opt, where third-party binaries are typically kept. It then downloads the Franz icon and creates a .desktop file, which is what allows the application to show up in your launcher.

Comment: It can be unpacked anywhere and run as 'portable'

Answer (score 0):

I'm no totally sure, but I think that you should install **libgcrypt11** to make it work properly.

You can do it here:

32 bits: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_i386.deb

64 bits: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb

Try it after GDog solution if it doesn't work.